# not working prev() on calendar of vuetify

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js, vcalendar

I generated vuetify calendar on my vue.js project.
you can see below on my code

```
<v-row>
    <v-btn icon  class="ma-2" @click="$refs.calendar.prev()">
       previous
    </v-btn>
</v-row>
 <v-calendar refs="calendar" :now="today" 
            :value="today"
            color="primary"></v-calendar>
```

but when i'm clicking previous button can't change currently displayed month on the calendar.
How I change current display month in calendar?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `:value="today"` by `v-model="today"`

Comment: @RakshaSaini Please pay attention when reviewing. This is definitely not a question, but clearly an answer to the question.